# Find the sum of tablespaces in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, tablespace

What I am trying to do is to calculate the sum of the 2 tableSpaces I have in my PostgreSQL DB.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_tablespace_size ('pg_default') );
```

with this query I am able to find the used space but when I modified it to find the details of both the tablespaces by using below query

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty ( pg_tablespace_size ('poolData')
                       ,pg_tablespace_size ('pool')    );
```

but it didn't gave any output. Is there any way to find both in a single query, so that I can calculate the sum of tablespaces?

Comment: A typo. `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size('poolData')), pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size ('pool'));`

Answer (score 0):

Function [`pg_tablespace_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) returns type `bigint`, so you can add them with a regular `+`.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_tablespace_size('poolData')
                      +pg_tablespace_size ('pool')    );
```

You can also `sum()` sizes of tablespaces you're interested in, fetching them from [`pg_tablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-tablespace.html).

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum(spcname)) from pg_tablespace
where spcname in ('poolData','pool');
```